# A downloaded webp image from a website could not be opened

Tags: macos, photos, preview

When I try to preview a downloaded image, I get an error:

```
The file “file-name.jpeg” could not be opened.
It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.
```

However Chrome browser can display the downloaded image just fine.

How can I preview such images?

Here is an example image in this [location](https://trek.scene7.com/is/image/TrekBicycleProducts/Procaliber98SL_19_23166_A_Portrait?$responsive-pjpg$&wid=1920&hei=1440). You can right-click and select `save the image as`.

Comment: Its a .jpeg so it shouldn’t be a problem with file type.

Comment: Have you tried opening it in a different application (anything would work, even pages) and see if you can view it? This will show whether the image is corrupted or  its s preview problem.

Comment: Using **Safari** and downloading the image linked in your OP, it opens just fine in **Preview**. How did you download the image to begin with?

Comment: I second that. The image opens perfectly fine in Preview for me. Can you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/382499/edit) your question to include the version of Preview and/or macOS you're using?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285698/webp-support-on-macos-is-it-indended-to-actually-work?rq=1 // @user3439894 they downloaded it via chrome/ Firefox with right click > "save image as" which saves it as webp as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular server seems to be changing data based on browser being used. For Safari, it loads jpeg image, thus downloadable and, openable by preview. For Firefox & chrome, it loads [WebP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP). Safari doesnt support that, neither [WebM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM). Both are sister projects by Google.

There are multiple ways you can open a WebP via, listed on linked Wikipedia page above. Some of which, I find easy on Mac, are:

- [Gimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP)
- [WebPQuickLook](https://github.com/emin/WebPQuickLook) as suggested in this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/339810/313842)
- Google web apps
- Other browsers like FireFox, Edge.
- Photoshop, with a plugin

This is how I did it:

```
wget  "https://trek.scene7.com/is/image/TrekBicycleProducts/Procaliber98SL_19_23166_A_Portrait?$responsive-pjpg$&wid=1920&hei=1440"
```

and rename it to add the extension .jpeg. It is openable by Preview, both with and without extension.

If you don't have wget, use `curl` available by default.

```
curl "https://trek.scene7.com/is/image/TrekBicycleProducts/Procaliber98SL_19_23166_A_Portrait?$responsive-pjpg$&wid=1920&hei=1440" >> ~/Downloads/name.jpeg
```

works just fine.

Comment: Interesting observation about different files being served for different browsers! Using Safari for download of images is the quickest solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [WEBP image](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp) (developed by Google) and Preview doesn't natively support this file type.  If you right click and select "View Image Info" you can get the image details (this one was done in Firefox)

[image]

There are a few ways you can view this image...

- [WebP Viewer](https://langui.net/webp-viewer/) (free).  Available on the [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/webp-viewer-quick-look-view/id1323414118?mt=12).  It's a Quick Look plugin and supports printing.  Supports Safari
- Browser Add-Ons:

  - Firefox: [WebP Image Converter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webp-image-converter/)
  - Chrome:  Built In tool
- Copy the image and paste it to another application then save it.  I used OneNote and was able to save the image as a JPG.  You can use other apps like Word, Pages, Notes, etc. and achieve the same results.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great writeup! It is much appreciated!